# Tronbox unbox and tronbox init commands are giving following error:-bash post-unpack.sh && rm post-unpack.sh && npm install

Tags: tronbox

```
tronbox unbox metacoin

Downloading...

Unpacking...

Setting up...

Error: Command failed: bash post-unpack.sh && rm post-unpack.sh && npm install

'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:289:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
```

I have tried the command tronbox unbox metacoon in windows 10. 
How to solve the above mentioned error? Same error is coming on trying command tronbox init. What can be the possible reasons for this bash error?

Answer (score 0):

**'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file'**

*This error comes when you try to run a shell script directly in window's command prompt.*

If this error comes while **unboxing metacoin DApp of tron**, there is nothing to worry about. Metacoin DApp will be unboxed properly in your specified directory.

In case of IDEs **Truffle or Tronbox**, Shell scripts are basically used for running some javascript file. So, if you using truffle or tronbox on Windows, you can run javascript file direclty without running shell script for it first.

**Solution for running javascript directly from window's command Prompt:-**

Open shell script in an editor and try to locate the name of the javascript file in it. Now you can run this javascipt file directly from window's command prompt.

You need to use the following command in Window's command prompt (pre-requisite:- node.js is installed in your system:-

**node filename.js**

I have tried this for both the IDEs, truffle and tronbox. It works just fine.